# IF empty cell = other empty cell return false

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make formula like:

```
IF(A1=B1,true,false)
```

But when A1 and B1 are empty, I want it to return false.

Only return true when A1 and B1 contain same word or number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
=IF(AND(NOT(COUNTBLANK(A1:B1)), A1=B1),true,false)
```

... or more simply as,

```
=AND(NOT(COUNTBLANK(A1:B1)), A1=B1)
```

Comment: For `A1=0` and `B1` empty it returns `true`. Last two sentences of OP are ambigous, so it is hard to say if that is correct result or not.

Comment: @BrakNicku - Fair enough; I wasn't considering all of the possibilities. Corrected above.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula:
=AND(A1=B1,NOT(ISBLANK(A1)))

[image]

Comment: as a note: If there are formulas in A and B that return `""` this will return a false positive.  ISBLANK will read them as having content.

Comment: You could switch to the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385). COUNTBLANK counts zero-length strings as blank. Maybe `=AND(A1=B1,NOT(COUNTBLANK(A1)))`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  So Len(A1) is both shorter and better.